# How can I call my java program from stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, jakarta-mail, java-stored-procedures

I am new at this. I have a java code that creates a mail invite. I need that code to be called in a oracle stored procedure. I use the loadjava utility to load the external mail and activation jar files into the oracle database.
Only the mail jar is loaded.
Also, the mail jar has package missing and now I need to reload the updated jar. I use dropjava command.
I still see the old jar file in the sql developer.
Can anyone help?

Comment: There's way too many questions in there, and I can only help with a few.  You don't need the activation jar file because it's included in all recent versions of the JDK.  Where did you get the JavaMail jar file that you're loading?  You want the javax.mail.jar file listed [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).  Most of the rest of your questions need a Java-in-the-database expert.

Comment: I know I am using the wrong jar. That is why I need to unload the jar and load the newer one. I am facing issue in reloading the jar file